# Motherboard does not support exact RAM speed

Tags: memory, motherboard

So i have a B350M GAMING PRO being delivered to me tommorow.

In the official MSI site in the specifications section for the product, it's written that the motherboard supports 1866/ 2133/ 2400/ 2667(OC)/ 2933(OC)/ 3200(OC)+ MHz DDR4 memory speeds.

The problem is that because of the way prices are formed in my country and of an ongoing sale, buying  HyperX FURY Red 8GB DDR4 2666MHz would be cheaper than the 2400MHz verison.

Will it be a problem, or would the RAM just downscale to the max not OC value - 2400Mhz ?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It will be a problem and you will probably get blue screens / memory problems with it. You should replace the memory you got for one of the supported speeds.

Answer (score 1):

Usually you can set the ram speed in the BIOS and if you select 2400MHz the memory will just work at that speed. The manual from MSI seems to be garbage so I can't tell the exact options required.